# icCube use mdx colors bug in amcharts combo

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

I set useMdxMemberColors to 'yes' in the widget and the colors do not change.

[image]

The mdx colors are defined in the builder like this:

[image]

I think this is a bug, but if not, is there a workaround or am I doing something wrong?

My icCube version: icCube Web Reporting : 5.1.1 ( 6:2229 )

Answer (score 0):

It's working (see image or [check live](http://www.iccube.com/livedemo/?ic3reportName=Using%20MDX%20Schema%20Colors)).

Is the MDX statement row axis the products ?

[image: icCube's example, MDX colors]